# Marketing Cloud to s3

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket I would like to transfer data to daily via automation. It currently doesn't look like there is a native way to transfer data into s3 via a file transfer activity. Has anyone had any success with passing data from marketing cloud to an s3 bucket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t do this directly between SFMC and S3. However, AWS has launched their [fully managed SFTP service for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/) last year. If you have management access to the AWS environment and can configure this service, establishing a connection between S3 and SFMC should be straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Update to anyone finding this topic today: Salesforce Marketing Cloud released a S3 File Location during the April Release 2021 where you should be able to pickup any files directly from AWS S3 via import activities, though the automations would have to be scheduled.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I've posted this question on the S3 integration topic here in the Salesforce StackExchange, and am wondering if you can help me understand some details, please? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361067/how-to-create-a-public-private-key-for-aws-s3-to-be-used-as-sfmc-file-location

Answer (score 0):

What I understood so far is we need the direction SFMC to S3. For the other way around we have, as mentioned, the file location feature.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the 2 year delay in answering the question!

Please follow these steps in order to transfer from Salesforce Marketing Cloud into Amazon S3 using Automation Studio:

1. Setup an AWS S3 File Transfer Location (FTL)
   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_set_up_amazon_s3_location.htm&type=5
2. Create an Automation with Start Source Schedule - Daily (also, I recommend not starting at the top of the hour, that is the default and over 99% of automations are scheduled this way, you'll have improved success if you start at the 50 minute mark)
   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5
3. Create a File Transfer Activity
   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5

Hope this helps - with this approach files can be transferred from Salesforce Marketing Cloud into any FTL, today we support the following:

Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure Blob Storage, Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP Site, Marketing Cloud Safehouse, External FTP, SFTP, or FTPS, and Salesforce Objects and Reports

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5