# How to create a public/private key for AWS S3 to be used as SFMC File Location

Tags: marketing-cloud, amazon-s3, amazon-aws

Since I had this same question as presented here and I found it being already asked, so I have copied this question over from the StackOverflow platform and added some details for more clarity.
Original question by @HamzahJamal

> I was trying to setup FTP folder in SFMC File Locations. In location
> type I found AWS S3. I was all excited, as this was my end goal. I did
> not want to write another automation to move from FTP to S3. However,
> to configure it I must provide Public/Private Key. Role ARN I can
> obtain from AWS, but as far as I know, public/private keys are only
> used to SSH into a machine and not S3. All I get from AWS is a pair of
> access-key-id and secret-access-key.

[image]

[The documentation on this feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Amazon%20Web%20Services%20(AWS)%20S3%20Bucket) is so brief that there are almost no descriptions for the attributes that need to be sent nor there's any sample usage.

[October 2021 feature release notes about this feature.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_october_2021_setup_as_sftp.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two keys turn out to be the public access key and secret access key for the IAM rule that's used to access the S3 bucket and is set when creating a file location for the S3 bucket in the marketing cloud. I set up a testing environment and went through some trials to confirm this.

Comment: Isn't that the information I provided?

Comment: Sorry, but no they aren't the same. The most important part of knowing what those keys are, is in this part of my answer: "public access key and secret access key for the IAM rule that's used to access the S3 bucket".

Comment: Can you provide any additional detail on how/where to find these?

Comment: @StanAlachniewicz you should be able to find the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html

Comment: Thanks @Bahman.A I was actually able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Public Key  == Access key ID

Private key  == Secret Access key

Comment: Thanks, @EazyE, can you also post a reference link, please?